# SaveAs function does not work, How to fix it?

Tags: asp.net

I write a code to save covid files into a folder but when I click on Save, The page become blank. I tested it and I notice the `FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath)` does not work.
Here is the code:

```
<script runat="server">

  protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    String savePath = @"..\Servername\Test_EOROOT\COVIDVaccinationUploads\";
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
      String fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
      savePath += fileName;
      Response.Write(savePath);
      // Nothing will happen from here...
      FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
      Response.Write(savePath);
      UploadStatusLabel.Text = "Your file was saved as " + fileName;
    }
    else
    {      
      UploadStatusLabel.Text = "You did not specify a file to upload.";
    }

  }
</script>
```

[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8orM.png)

[and here is what happen after I click on Upload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjhKu.png)

Comment: are you getting an exceptions? if so you might want to use `Server.MapPath`

Comment: Thank you @DanielA.White, I use `String savePath = Server.MapPath(@"..\SJS-tonsap001.sjs.cloud.lc\Test_EOROOT\COVIDVaccinationUploads\");` and the path is now absolute.But still it stuck on blank page